# Citus: How can I add self referencing table in distributed tables list

Tags: postgresql, sharding, citus

I'm trying to run `create_distributed_table` for tables which i need to shard and almost all of the tables have self relation ( parent child )
but when I run `SELECT create_distributed_table('table-name','id');`
it throws error `cannot create foreign key constraint`

simple steps to reproduce

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  ID        TEXT                 NOT NULL,
  NAME      CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
  PARENT_ID TEXT
);

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID);

ALTER TABLE TEST  ADD CONSTRAINT TEST_PARENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_ID) REFERENCES TEST (ID);
```

ERROR

```
citus=> SELECT create_distributed_table('test','id');
ERROR:  cannot create foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Foreign keys are supported in two cases, either in between two colocated tables including partition column in the same ordinal in the both tables or from distributed to reference tables
```

Comment: As far as I understand, distributed tables are sharded. How should a foreign key between tables in different databases work? I'd say you either have to do without the constraint or without the distributed table.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe so it's a limitation of citus or is it related to sharding ? 
I have almost 70% of tables with such nested relation, It doesn't have much benefit of using sharding for the rest 30%.

Comment: I'd say that this is a fundamental property of sharding. Sharding is not just randomly putting parts of the data in different buckets, you have to shard so that you split the data in mostly independent parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being, it is not possible to shard a table on PostgreSQL without dropping the self referencing foreign key constraints, or altering them to include a separate and new distribution column.

Citus places records into shards based on the hash values of the distribution column values. It is most likely the case that the hashes of parent and child id values are different and hence the records should be stored in different shards, and possibly on different worker nodes. PostgreSQL does not have a mechanism to create foreign key constraints that reference records on different PostgreSQL clusters.

Consider adding a new column `tenant_id` and adding this column to the primary key and foreign key constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  tenant_id INT                    NOT NULL,
  id        TEXT                   NOT NULL,
  name      CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
  parent_id TEXT                   NOT NULL,

  FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id, parent_id) REFERENCES test(tenant_id, id),
  PRIMARY KEY (tenant_id, id)
);

SELECT create_distributed_table('test','tenant_id');
```

Note that parent and child should always be in the same tenant for this to work.

Comment: hmm, makes sense but even if distribution column is other than `Id` e.g `tenent_id` it still doesn't allow such relations.

Comment: That's because there is no guarantee that the `tenant_id` values for the original record and parent will be the same. 

Consider the we have two (`tenant_id`, `id`, `parent_id`) triples: (1,100, 200), (2, 200, 300). The parent and child can hit different shards due to different `tenant_id` values, and this would break the foreign key.

Citus is cautious and does not allow fk constraints in this case.

Comment: @MohsinAmjad I added an alternative solution, and edited my answer above. Please check if this works for you

Comment: yes, that worked, so basically all of the foreign key constraints must include tenant_id just like you added for parent_id ? let's say
if i have b_id which is foreign key of table B then the constraint should be 
something like `FOREIGN KEY (b_id,tenant_id) REFERENCES B(id,tenant_id)` otherwise it won't allow ?
also I've added one more constraint in your example `FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenant(id)`.

Comment: Yes, and yes. All your unique/primary/foreign key constraints should include distribution columns.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, citus docs lack such examples.